# Installing ScintillaNET, cannot add libraries in Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I want to add Scintilla to my project, because I want to make my own HTML editor.

Visual Studio doesn't want to add a reference to `SciLexer.dll` and `SciLexer64.dll`.

I've dont everything in the [installation instructions](https://scintillanet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Installation&referringTitle=Documentation).

I'm using Windows 7 64 bit and Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Formatting, minor copy-edits. Rephrased title. Still lacks a detailed problem description (error message, ...).

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty clear in the documentation.  You want to reference only `ScintillaNET.dll` in your project, and ensure that `SciLexer.dll` and `SciLexer64.dll` are somewhere in your path.  The `ScintillaNET.dll` is a wrapper around the two other unmanaged DLL's, and used P/Invoke to call them.

This means that you need to ensure that the unmanaged DLL's are deployed with your application.

Comment: Cool, but I still don't know how to add them into my Project :/
Even if they really are somewhere in my path I cannot use the ScintillaNET because the ScintillaNET needs them to work :/ .

Comment: So this is for deployment?  Instead of adding a reference, maybe add the files directly in a "deployment" folder under the solution, and then include them in your deployment package (i.e. so they are written to the location of your program)